# llvm builder adding terminator to basic block

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

If I have a basic block declared within function F like so:

```
BasicBlock* loopSetup = BasicBlock::Create(F.getContext(), "loop_setup", &F);
```

How would I add a terminator instruction to it? If I just do:

```
IRBuilder<> builder(loopSetup);
builder.SetInsertPoint(loopSetup);
BranchInst *end = builder.CreateBr(loopStart);
```

Then I get this error on running the pass with opt:

```
Basic Block in function 'main' does not have terminator!
label %loop_setup
```

The terminator is clearly not set as well since `loopSetup->getTerminator();` returns 0.

Comment: Where does it end up, though? Try calling F.dump(). (Pro tip: there's a dump() on almost every class, and if the landscape doesn't seem to match your map it's a quick way to look at the landscape.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided, with some changes, seems to work fine..

```
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace llvm;

int main() {
    LLVMContext context;

    std::unique_ptr<Module> TheModule = std::make_unique<Module>(std::string("mod"), context);

    FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getVoidTy(context), std::vector<Type*>(), false);

    Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", TheModule.get());

    BasicBlock* loopSetup = BasicBlock::Create(context, "loop_setup", F);

    IRBuilder<> builder(loopSetup);
    builder.SetInsertPoint(loopSetup);
    BranchInst *end = builder.CreateBr(loopSetup);

    TheModule->print(errs(), nullptr);
}
```

This creates an endless loop. Calling `loopSetup->getTerminator()->print(errs(), false)` shows that the `br` used is the terminator of the block.

The IR output seems fine too

```
define void @main() {
loop_setup:
  br label %loop_setup
}
```

The problem might be with `loopStart` you used, as you didn't show how you created it.